# Is it possible to add custom autonumbering lists in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

InDesign CC comes with a set of pre-defined autonumbering lists:

1.2.3.

a.b.c.

0001, 0002, 0003.... etc.

Is there a way to add a custom autonumbering list such as Cyrillic letters or custom numbering such as 000001? InDesign MiddleEastern version does add Hebrew and Arabic numbering systems and Japanese version adds Chinese and Japanese numbering systems but nothing is customizable. For that matter InDesign's Object Reference only covers the lists I mention above (incl. Eastern and Japanese).

Is there any answers to that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the answer is **no**.

The question has been asked in the [Adobe Support Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/creating-custom-numbering-system/m-p/11129860) on May 14, 2020 by user Pandazis Dimakis:

> By default, InDesign has very specific set of numbering formats,
> numerals, latin numerals and latin letters. I want to create a
> numbering system that uses greek letters, not latin. Does anyone know
> if this is possible and how?

Manan Joshi, Adobe Community Professional, answers:

> There is no inbuilt solution for this, not do i know if any plugin
> that could help. Look at the following discussion that talks about a
> workaround by using custom typeface
> https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/custom-numbering-style-format/td-p/10412802

I also find two almost identical *Feature Requests*: [one from 2018](https://indesign.uservoice.com/forums/601021-adobe-indesign-feature-requests/suggestions/33975283-customizing-numbering-style-format) and [one from 2020](https://indesign.uservoice.com/forums/601021-adobe-indesign-feature-requests/suggestions/41273761-to-add-an-option-to-add-a-customized-numbering-for). It doesn't seem like much is happening in this regard.

---

I assume you are aware that it's pretty easy to *manually* create custom numbered lists using *Left Indent*, *First Line Left Indent*, a *Tab* and a *Tab* character (or alternatively the *Indent To Here* character, a *Tab* and a *Tab* character).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Wolff. Yes, I do know how to create lists manually. But I'm more interested in automatic numbering aspect of it, not just the design/layout. As an alternative solution one could create a custom font with abc replaced with абв or something of the sort - I resorted to this in the past but its application is very limited... and tedious.

Comment: One more alternative would be to write a script that uses autonumbering but changes the numbering string based on a specific language. In fact I have it for Greek and Russian - it creates an override but saves time on automatic numbering.